# Windows 10 privacy: How are apps inserted into the categories (camera, email, etc.) and then blocked?

Tags: windows-10, privacy

I am developing machine control software for machines of my company. The software is currently running under Windows 7 Pro SP1.
Inside these machines, GigE cameras and USB cameras are used. Also, we plan to add an email feedback functionality to report machine status and failures.

We're now migrating to Windows 10 Enterprise LTSB (a.k.a. Windows 10 IoT). I am about to set up a reference installation and facing some questions when configuring the privacy settings:

- How does Windows 10 know, that a program accesses hardware (cameras, microphone), in order to list that program in the corresponding category of the privacy settings and possibly block access to the hardware?
- How does Windows 10 know, that a program can send emails, in order to list it in the email category and possibly block it from sending emails?

Regarding hardware, I can think of blocking access to the hardware driver, but I don't know if this is true.
Regarding emails, I have no idea how Windows does that.

We will probably have to try all that out, but I'd like to configure the Windows installation correctly now, because it will be hard to change settings on many computers at many different customers later.

Comment: Probable idea: Windows make default email program with the `mailto:` URI. So whenever you click email address it redirects to the `mailto:` registry and find default path of that program.

Comment: @Biswapriyo: unlikely. In this case only the default program could be blocked. But I think that all programs with email functionality will be listed, otherwise the blocking funcion is pretty useless.

Comment: *Windows 10 Enterprise LTSB* isn’t also known as *Windows 10 IoT*.  They are two completely different SKUs. Raspberry Pi 3 supports Windows 10 IoT but it does not support Windows 10 LTSB.

Comment: @Ramhound: Raspberry PI supports Windows 10 IoT CORE. That's a different version. Win 10 IoT *is* Windows 10 Enterprise LTSB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How does Windows 10 know, that a program accesses hardware (cameras, microphone), in order to list that program in the corresponding category of the privacy settings and possibly block access to the hardware?

Because that program is calling the Windows API (programming interface) for accessing the camera, microphone, etc. Windows can register that as it sits between the hardware and the program.

A driver often only implements the required interface (e.g. camera interface) to provide Windows the capability to control the hardware.

> How does Windows 10 know, that a program can send emails, in order to list it in the email category and possibly block it from sending emails?

When using the Windows API's for sending e-mail Windows can register that too. If a program sends an e-mail via a different way, e.g. a POST request to a web url or connects via TCP sockets to some smtp server, and the app doesn't explicitely register the mailto: handler, then Windows cannot detect that it's sending mail.

Comment: My software will NOT use the Windows API, it directly implements the driver of the camera manufacturer. Does this bypass the blocking functionality?  
On emails: okay, in general the same as for the hardware: If windows APIs are not used, Windows will not know and not block it?

Comment: @TobiasKnauss true, if you don't use Windows API's but special direct driver interfaces then Windows won't know. It's possible but not recommended.

Comment: I just tested the Basler Pylon Viewer, IDS uEye Cockpit and Matrox MIL10: they all did not register as camera apps, which makes sense: Their usage does not target a simple end-user (who wants maximum convenience), but industrial applications (which need maximum performance). These programs resp. their APIs transmit data in high-speed and offer the cameras full functionality, thus they cannot use any Windows API.